# How to access Cpanel on 1&1(IONOS) hosting?

Tags: hosting, cpanel

Does anyone know how to access Cpanel on 1&1(IONOS). One of the biggest in the web hosting market but I didn't know it was one of the worst. Knowledge Base is empty. Searching on Google doesn't result in anything.

**I am startled by the fact that I found NO INFORMATION online. Absolutely NO information on google. How could it be possible? No one has ever tried to ask this question before?!?!?** BTW IONOS is the worst web host. If someone has to search for 20 mins to access even cpanel, then it's the worst web host.

[IONOS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSsz7.png)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 2):

I nearly fell for their $6-for-the-first-year Business Plan account. Whups! Good thing I asked some questions first.

The sales person answered the chat after approx 20 mins, and was not customer friendly. When I enquired about included CPanel apps, I was abruptly told that CPanel is not included - you must purchase it separately. She did not tell me (this is what I mean by "abrupt"), but I read elsewhere, that they wrote their own "CPanel-like" administration tool - but from what I can tell it is significantly less capable. And as of this writing, I still do not know if they offer Node.js (which was something that I asked the sales rep but she did not answer).

I would be interested to see a screenshot of the IONOS CPanel replacement. I also would like to know what included apps they offer, such as phpBB, SimpleMachinesForum, Node.js, Python, Ruby - and how Git management/deployment works. As of this writing, and over 30 minutes on chat with them (including wait time), I have no idea.

Here is a fairly recently article from Dec 2021 that sheds more light:

https://websitesetup.org/hosting-reviews/ionos/

Answer (score 1):

Note the below is only available if you have the right build assigned to your account.

Server administration with Plesk is conveniently done right in your browser.
Since Plesk provides its own HTTPS service for this, a web server (e.g. Apache)
does not need to be running on the server.

Open your web browser and enter your domain name (or IP address)
followed by :8443 in the address bar.

Log in with the user name Admin and your initial password.
You can log in to IONOS and find your initial password in the Server Access Data section.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure by now you managed to fix your problem. But I figured I must just post how I accessed it for other people. I am assuming that you wanted to remove some of the files on your website (i.e. if a WordPress plugin destroyed your site). The way I accessed my files is as follows: Firstly go to your Ionos dashboard. Then click on the contract you are using (i.e. WP Business). Thereafter go to hosting and click manage, then a page will open and click webspace. Once you click webspace you will be able to access all of your files.

I hope this helps someone out because truly getting information about Ionos seems like thesis research.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your Cpanel using below URL,

http://IP:2082

Note: In IP you have to set your Cpanel IP.

above link redirect to login page, In login page you need to enter your username and password,

Answer (score 0):

From the look of your screenshot it looks as if the package you have purchased is not one that contains a server.  Here are two options for packages with servers.

- [Cloud](https://www.ionos.com/cloud/cloud-servers#packages)
- [Dedicated](https://www.ionos.com/servers/managed-server)

[Ref](http://aklam.io/jyliiY)

Answer (score -2):

Go to Servers & Cloud -> Infrastructure -> Servers and select the server you want to access.

Then, go to either the Plesk or cPanel section, there you'll find user, password and host for your server.